# Hook after creating content

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

I want to add some specific treatment after creating the content.

[Rules module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) is for similar cases but I look for a hook.

Is there a hook that triggers just after creating content (node)?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement [`hook_node_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7.x), which is called after a node is created or updated, but before the node is saved in the database.

```php
function mymodule_node_presave($node) {
  // $node->original contains the node object before the edits.
  if ($node->nid && $node->moderate && $node->original->moderate != $node->moderate) {
    $node->score = 0;
    $node->users = '';
    $node->votes = 0;
  }
}
```